# Problem using JS ES6 promises in React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I import the function `getWeather` from another .js file I've written. The result is a json blob. I've verified that I get the JSON blob back, but when I try to call the `getWeather` function and use .then to wait for a response and set my state I get a TypeError.

```
getWeather(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(long)).then((data) =>{
  this.setState({weatherType: data.currently.icon, temp: data.currently.temperature})
  return data
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error.message);
})
```

The `getWeather` function is here:

```
export function getWeather(lat,long) {
  const params = {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    method: "GET"
      };
      fetch(`https://api.com/mykey/${lat},${long}`, params)
        .then(function (data) {
          return data.json();
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: without seeing your getWeather function I'm only guessing but you may not be returning a promise.

Comment: I'll add more info

Comment: yea you aren't returning anything from `getWeather`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return fetch()` in order to make the promise accessible from another function. Also, I would probably handle logging and errors in the calling function as when you log the data you are no longer returning it.

```
export function getWeather(lat,long) {
  const params = {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    method: "GET"
      };
      return fetch(`https://api.com/mykey/${lat},${long}`, params)
        .then(function (data) {
          if (!data.ok) { return new Error('custom error message here') }
          return data.json();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably return that blob from the getWeather function without creating a Promise.
Try something like this:

```js
function getWeather() {
// create blob as usual
  return Promise.resolve(blob);
}
```

or if you already inside a then you must just retrun something from it:

```js
      fetch(`https://api.com/mykey/${lat},${long}`, params)
        .then(function (data) {
          return data.json();
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);

          retrun res; // return something 

        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```